# Inverse Fourier Transform of a Constant

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The Fourier transform and its inverse can be defined as $$\mathcal{F}(f(x))=F(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-ikx} \ dx \ \ \text{and} \ \ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(F(k))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(k)e^{ikx} \ dk$$ respectively.
Now, the Fourier transform of a constant, $a$,  is $$\mathcal{F}(a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ae^{-ikx} \ dx=a\sqrt{2\pi}\delta(k),$$ where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function. My question is, what is $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(a)$? Is it, by symmetry of the Fourier transform and its inverse, $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(a)=a\sqrt{2\pi}\delta(-x)?$$

**Simple proof:**

Let $x=k_1$, then
$$\mathcal{F}(f(k_1))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(k_1)e^{-ikk_1} \ dk_1.$$Now let $k=-x_1$, then $$\mathcal{F}(f(k_1))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(k_1)e^{ix_1k_1} \ dk_1.$$ Does this provide proof of my argument?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $1$ is $\sqrt{2\pi} \delta$ because for any $\varphi$ (nice enough : smooth and $L^1$..) the Fourier transform of $1 . \varphi$ is $\mathcal{F}(\varphi) \ast \delta$. In other words for a distribution its Fourier transform is the unique distribution that fits well in the convolution theorem(s). The Fourier inversion theorem stays true for distributions, that is from $\mathcal{F}(\delta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ you know  $\mathcal{F}^{-1}( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}) = \delta$

Comment: @reuns but what about the argument of the delta function (this is what I am concerned about)? I want to know if you replace $k$ with $-x$ when taking the inverse Fourier transform of a function to the frequency space (hence $\delta(-x)$).

Comment: The Dirac delta "function" is not a function, it is a measure.  When you speak of "inverse," you need to be specific about the domain and range of the function [Fourier Transform] you are speaking of.

Comment: When we take the fourier transform of a test function, standard Gaussian for example, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{itx}\mbox{d}x=e^{i\mu t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma t)^2}$$ and when $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$ we have $$|e^{i\mu t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma t)^2}|\rightarrow 1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defining formula
$$\mathcal{F}f(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, dx$$
only works when $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$ The Fourier transform can however be extended to several other cases. For example, for a [tempered distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) $u$ it is defined to be the distribution $\mathcal{F}u$ satisfying
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x) \, \mathcal{F}\varphi(x) \, dx,$$
for all test functions $\varphi$ in [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R}).$

One example of a tempered distribution is $\delta.$ Its Fourier transform is thus given by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}\delta(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) \, \mathcal{F}\varphi(x) \, dx
= \mathcal{F}(0)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, dx \right|_{k=0}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \varphi(x) \, dx
,
$$
i.e.
$\mathcal{F}\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ (constant function).

For $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ we have $\mathcal{F}^2\varphi(x) = \varphi(-x),$ and it's easy to show from this that also for tempered distributions we have $\mathcal{F}^2 u(x) = u(-x).$ Therefore, for the constant function $1$ we have
$$
\mathcal{F}1(x) 
= \mathcal{F}\{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\mathcal{F}\delta\}(x)
= \sqrt{2\pi}\,\mathcal{F}^2\delta(x)
= \sqrt{2\pi}\,\delta(-x)
= \sqrt{2\pi}\,\delta(x).
$$

Comment: So for the inverse Fourier transform of a function, say $e^{-a|k|}$, is $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-a|k|})=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}?$$

Comment: That is correct. We have 
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{-a|x|}) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{a}{a^2+k^2}$$
and
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-a|k|}) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}.$$